# Google Docs Script Issue with Split through Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time poster here for Google Script related services, hopefully I put it in the right place! I'm encountering an error and I can't seem to find the right terminology to look up a solution. Below is the function. Within it I have a variable, string1, that I apply the split to. If I hard-code the value of the string (in the line commented out in the string), then it works and I receive the correct output. If, on the other hand, I try to pass that string into the function from another function, I receive the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot find function split in object Wed Oct 30 2013 09:00:26 GMT-0400 (EDT),danno,ticket,netid,request,mac,Error - Invalid Mac / Mac Not Found."

Note: My call to the function looks like this - formatEmailRow(completeEmailArray[i])

```
function formatEmailRow(rowToFormat) {
  var formattedString = "";
  var array1 = [];
  var string1 = "";
  ///////////////////////
  string1 = rowToFormat;
  //string1 ="10/30/2013 9:00:26,danno,ticket,netid,request,mac,Error  - Invalid Mac / Mac Not Found ";
  ///////////////////////
  array1 = string1.split(",| ,|, ");
  if (array1 != ""){
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  formattedString = formattedString + "     " +(array1[i]);
  }}
  return formattedString;
  }
```

Please help! 
Thanks ahead of time, any advice is appreciated!

-Danno

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `.split()` isn't a method contained in the type of object you've passed in. Since you're new to this, it's worth a pause to read up on Objects and Methods - [this is a quick overview](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

You want to receive a String, but it seems that you're not. The problem will be with the code that's calling `formatEmailRow()`.

My guess is that you're passing an array - probably all the cells in a row - but here's how you can check.

Add this line as the first line in your function:

```
Logger.log("rowToFormat = " + JSON.stringify(rowToFormat));
```

... then run, with your error. Check the logs - you want to see that you are getting a simple string. If you're getting an array, then you know what you need to fix. (Maybe you want to get the array after all!)